# Guess type of matrix in template

Tags: c++

I am practicing c++ templates by trying to write a code where I can save a matrix of an arbitrary type to a csv file. I already have some coding working except that I have to pass an useless parameter so that the function knows what type of data composes the matrix. How do I get rid of it?

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <
typename num,
class Matrix = vector<vector<num>>
>

void matrix_to_csv(Matrix X, string filename, num useless){
  fstream file;
  file.open(filename, fstream::out);
  for(int i = 0; i<X.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<X[0].size(); j++){
      file << X[i][j] <<",";
    }
    file<<"\n";
  }
  file.close();
}
```

Example:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> M = {
                        {1,2,5,8},
                        {4,3,1,2},
                        {1,6,5,4}
                        };
matrix_to_csv(M,"result.csv",0);
```

Comment: Die you try `void matrix_to_csv(Matrix X, string filename)`?

Comment: Yes, it says that it couldn't deduce template parameter ‘num’

Comment: How do you use the function?

Comment: For  a matrix vector<vector<int>> M = {
                        {1,2,5,8},
                        {4,3,1,2},
                        {1,6,5,4}
                        };

Comment: I use it like this matrix_to_csv(M,"result.csv",0)

Comment: Don't post code as comment. Create a [mcve]

Comment: I just pasted the code, X is the same as M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to completely "get rid of it" in the sense that if the compiler can't deduce the type from `x`, then you will need some way for the compiler to know the type.

That said, instead of passing a parameter you don't use, you do have this instead:

```
matrix_to_csv<num>(X,"result.csv");
```

Where `num` is the type that you want.

---

**Note:** If you are not using `Matrix` anywhere else, you do have the option to make your template header simpler:

```
template <typename num>
void matrix_to_csv(vector<vector<num>> X, string filename){
```

However, this is just personal preference, I suppose.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `Matrix` and use the template parameter like that

```
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename num>
void matrix_to_csv(vector<vector<num>> X, string filename){
  fstream file;
  file.open(filename, fstream::out);
  for(const auto &row : X){
    for(const auto &el : row) {
      file << el <<",";
    }
    file<<"\n";
  }
  file.close();
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> M = {
                            {1,2,5,8},
                            {4,3,1,2},
                            {1,6,5,4}
                            };
    matrix_to_csv(M,"result.csv");
}
```

In your example `vector<vector<num>>` is the default parameter if no parameter is given. But you pass `vector<vector<int>>` and `Matrix` is set to `vector<vector<int>>`. There is no relation between `int` and `num` in your example. You can alternatively use `Matrix` instead of `num`

```
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename Matrix>
void matrix_to_csv(Matrix X, string filename){
  fstream file;
  file.open(filename, fstream::out);
  for(const auto &row : X){
    for(const auto &el : row) {
      file << el <<",";
    }
    file<<"\n";
  }
  file.close();
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> M = {
                            {1,2,5,8},
                            {4,3,1,2},
                            {1,6,5,4}
                            };
    matrix_to_csv(M,"result.csv");
}
```